# Is there an SQL function that can calculate the average value of a specific column in a table?

Tags: sql, stack, spreadsheet

I needed to inquire about the availability of a specific SQL function that could perform a common aggregation task. In particular, I was interested in finding out if there was a built-in SQL function that could calculate the average value of a specific column within a table. This was important because I was working on a data analysis project, and I needed to compute the average of a particular numerical attribute to gain insights from the data.

**Identified the specific task at hand:** Calculating the average of a column in a SQL table.
**Considered the context:** I was working with a relational database and wanted to leverage SQL functions to perform this calculation.
**Composed the question:** I crafted a clear and concise question, "Is there an SQL function that can calculate the average value of a specific column in a table?" to seek information about the existence of such a function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the AVG function is your answer.
Exemple of use :

```
SELECT 
  AVG(your_column_name) as avg_of_your_column
FROM your_table
```

You can also make aggregation based on other column value :

```
SELECT 
  another_column, 
  AVG(your_column_name) as avg_of_your_column
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY another_column
```

See doc here : https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/func_sqlserver_avg.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with the use of the **AVG()** built-in function.
Here are an example of usage:

```
SELECT AVG(column) AS ColumnAverage
FROM table
```

Another example could be this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.column1 > (
    SELECT AVG(column2) 
    FROM table t)
```

**NOTE** that this function in Microsoft SQL Server will ignore the *NULL* value.

If you want more information you can check directly on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or on the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg).